# Field dependency not applying for Billing state and billing country standard fields in LWC component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, dependent-picklist, address, compound-fields

I have the functionality to create an LWC form with billing address fields(Billing address is a compound field). But when I create the form I can see the Billing country & state picklist fields but field dependency isn't applying for those. For example, If the country is the US it should only show US states.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you referred to this? - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/documentation

Comment: @TusharJadav- Yeah but if we use that we need to give the picklist values manually but I want to use the menus already present in the Account billing Address field.